# Woff 2 font with font collection inside

Tags: fonts, woff2

Currently I am working on my own font parser.

WOFF2 is one of the formats I want to support.

In specs says WOFF2 supports font collections, but I cannot find such fonts.

Simply no info in google about such font files.

So, I came here to ask someone to help me with it and provide at least few such files for testing purposes.
Please, help me with my issue.

Comment: Is your question about where to find font collection files, or where to find WOFF2 files containing a font collection?

Comment: @PeterConstable My question is where to find WOFF2 files containing a font collection

Comment: There are online tools that can generate woff2. Have you tried taking a .ttc file and converting using one of the various online tools?

Comment: @PeterConstable Sorry, but I didnt find any converter that could correctly convert ttc to WOFF2 and set it`s Flavor to correct value. If you know converter that could do conversion correctly, please write it here. I would appreciate for help

Answer (score 1):

Check out [woff2](https://github.com/google/woff2), which supports WOFF2 Collections.

Comment: unfortunately this simply does not work. I dont know why, but binaries does not want to convert any font

Comment: I would be interested to know what particular error messages you encountered, and what particular TTCs you tried to convert to WOFF2 Collections, because I had no problems compiling and executing the tools.